# Create Ratio in Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring, log-based-metrics

I have two user defined log based metrics of type counter, resource type cloud_run_revision, kind delta, value type INT64.

I want to create a widget using the menu driven interface that displays the ratio of the metrics as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer). After I add the queries to the metric explorer and I click on the create ratio, in the dropdown the queries could not be selected and the error is "You must specify a resource type for the numerator and denominator of a ratio." The group by None and Sum and Alignment function is Count over 1d for both of them.

Is this a common issue or I am missing something here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated this issue and i’m able to create the chat ratio metrics perfectly but can you cross check on the below points:

- While adding the metrics to metrics explorer , you need to select the resources for which you are going to create the ratios. If we don’t select, we can't move further.
- While adding the metrics , for Group By Label you are selecting “NONE”, maybe this might cause you the error "You must specify a resource type for the numerator and denominator of a ratio." So, Can you select the Group By label resource also and have a try.
- Can you refer to these [Select metrics when using Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#basic-advanced-mode) and [Restrictions with ratios](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metric-ratios#restrict) for more information.

Comment: The problem was related to the fact that I selected the metric from the Unspecified resources dropdown in the UI. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @razvan.todea : Glad that your issue resolved, YES while selecting the mertics, under filter you need to select the `Active resource & Metrics` then this will show only specified resources that are active.